# Why when I merge tables in mysql database the values are duplicating?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, join

I am trying to count how many times a value (example: 1st place) appears in a column from 3 different tables.

I merge 4 tables by ID to get the columns I need, and then do a array to get all the values, then I use array_count_values to find out how many times the value is in the table.

it does what I want for the most part, except that the answer is doubled. When actually the value only appears 1 time, once I merge the tables each value is showing up more than it should.

these are my tables before I merged them

Table 1

```
| dancer_id | dancer_placement1|
|    1      |   2nd Place      |
|    1      |   1st Place      |
|    3      |   4th Place      |
```

table 2

```
| dancer_id | dancer_placement3|
|    1      |   4th Place      |
|    1      |   1st Place      |
|    3      |   3rd Place      |
|    1      |   2nd Place      |
```

table 3

```
| dancer_id | dancer_placement3|
|    2      |   6th Place      |
|    3      |   1st Place      |
|    1      |   3rd Place      |
```

When I merge them it looks like this

```
| dancer_id | dancer_placement1|  dancer_placement2|  dancer_placement3|
|    1      |   2nd Place      |  4th Place        |  3rd Place        |    
|    1      |   1st Place      |  4th Place        |  3rd Place        |    
|    1      |   2nd Place      |  1st Place        |  3rd Place        |    
|    1      |   1st Place      |  1st Place        |  3rd Place        |
|    1      |   2nd Place      |  2nd Place        |  3rd Place        |
|    1      |   1st Place      |  2nd Place        |  3rd Place        |
```

It should actually look like this:

```
| dancer_id | dancer_placement1|  dancer_placement2|  dancer_placement3|
|    1      |   2nd Place      |  4th Place        |  3rd Place        |    
|    1      |   1st Place      |  1st Place        |  null             |    
|    1      |   null           |  2nd Place        |  null             |
```

As you can see before merging in dancer_placement1 "1st place" and "2nd place" only appears once, but after merging it appears 3 times.

in dancer_placement2 1st, 2nd, and 4th appear once, but after merging appears 2 times each.

in dancer_placement3 3rd place appears only once but after merging it appears 6 times.

I think there may be something wrong with my sql because everything else works as it should.

here is my code:

```php
//GET ID 

if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $childId=$_GET['id']; 
//I MERGE MY TABLES
    $chartsql = <<<_SQL
SELECT
  dancers.id, 
  mark_cards1.dancer_placement1, 
  mark_cards2.dancer_placement2, 
  mark_cards3.dancer_placement3 
FROM dancers 
LEFT JOIN mark_cards1 ON mark_cards1.dancer_id1 = dancers.id
LEFT JOIN mark_cards2 ON mark_cards2.dancer_id2 = dancers.id 
LEFT JOIN mark_cards3 ON mark_cards3.dancer_id3 = dancers.id 
WHERE dancers.id = '$childId'
_SQL;

$pieChartRes = mysqli_query($con,$chartsql);

 //BELOEW CODE WORKS PERFECTLY FINE

     // creating an array to find values
    while ($pieChartRow=mysqli_fetch_array($pieChartRes)){
        $first[] = $pieChartRow['dancer_placement1'];
        $second[] = $pieChartRow["dancer_placement2"];
        $third[]= $pieChartRow["dancer_placement3"];

    }

   // COUNTING THE AMOUNT OF TIMES A SPECIFIC VALUE APPEARS

    $tmp = array_count_values($first);
    $count_first = $tmp["1st place"];
    $count_second = $tmp["2nd place"];
    $count_third = $tmp["3rd place"];

    $tmp2 = array_count_values($second);
    $count_first2 = $tmp2["1st place"];
    $count_second2 = $tmp2["2nd place"];
    $count_third2 = $tmp2["3rd place"];

    $tmp3 = array_count_values($third);
    $count_first3 = $tmp3["1st place"];
    $count_second3 = $tmp3["2nd place"];
    $count_third3 = $tmp3["3rd place"];

  //PRINTING NUMBER OF VALUES

    echo "number of 1st place in dancerplacement1: $count_first";
    echo "number of 1st place in dancerplacement2: $count_first2";
    echo "number of 1st place in dancerplacement3: $count_first3";

    echo "number of 2nd place in dancerplacement1: $count_second";
    echo "number of 2nd place in dancerplacement2: $count_second2";
    echo "number of 2nd place in dancerplacement3: $count_second3";

    echo "number of 3rd place in dancerplacement1: $count_third";
    echo "number of 3rd place in dancerplacement2: $count_third2";
    echo "number of 3rd place in dancerplacement3: $count_third3";

// GETTING TOTALS

    $first_total = $count_first + $count_first2 + $count_first3;
    $second_total = $count_second + $count_second2 + $count_second3;
    $third_total = $count_third + $count_third2 + $count_third3;
    echo "total for first place = $first_total";
    echo "total for second place = $second_total";
    echo "total for third place = $third_total";
```

Comment: You should learn to use prepared statements instead of substituting variables into the SQL. Your code is open to SQL-injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Join use union all like below:

```
select dancerid,dancer_placement1,null as dancer_placement2,null as dancer_placement3
from table1 where dancerid=1
union all
select dancerid,null,dancer_placement2,null
from table2 where dancerid=1
union all
select dancerid,null,null,dancer_placement3
from table3 where dancerid=1
```

Comment: It works when I do the query in the database, but the heading is like this "id | null | null | dancer_placement3|. This however is not working when I query it on the profile.php page. I get the error Notice: Undefined index: dancer_placement2 in /home/hqwkui898g3u/public_html/dancerProfile.php on line 126

Comment: @TaahiraCarter You must have copied the query wrong. The column names should come from the aliases in the first query, so `null as dancer_placement2` should ensure that this index exists in the result.

Comment: @Barmar Yeas you were right I forgot to put "as" for dancer_placement2 thank you it works perfectly now.